# How to do a range query on a numeric property from Map/Reduce index in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm using Raven build 960 and I have a Map/Reduce reduce index. Some of the properties from the reduce function are numeric, however they are stored as strings. This [appears](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/FHKz1dgWHvw) to be expected behavior because Raven doesn't have type information at that point. The property deserializes properly into the corresponding numeric type, such as Int32, if the result class declares it as such. However, it breaks for range queries and compares the values as string as opposed to numeric values.

For example, one of the properties is weight originally stored as a decimal. When doing a range query such as: `Weight:[3 TO NULL]` in order to retrieve all documents with weight greater than 3 it will not return something with a weight of 20, since by lexicographical order "20" < "3".

In the index definition, I've indicated `SortOptions.Float` for weight and it sorts properly, but the range query still fails.

How can I do a range query on a numeric property in a Map/Reduce index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eulerfx,
We describe how we store the information in the index here:
http://ravendb.net/docs/appendixes/lucene-indexes-usage

For floats, you need to provide indication to raven about it.

```
Weight:[Fx3 TO NULL]
```

Will work